# The best way to return the results from server to mobile client

Tags: asp.net, windows-mobile

I'm creating a database application using ASP.NET and I want to make a Windows Mobile client. It should go like this - user opens the WM client, enters the text which he's looking for, the client then opens URL like Search.aspx?text=MyText and the WM client then says "Text Found" (if really found). And here's the problem. I don't know what's the best way to return search results back to the client. Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would implement a webservice that is accessed by the client, that would return data in xml format.